# How to parse a json with escaped string into smaller json with node js or python

Tags: python, node.js, json, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm using AWS step functions and want to parse the following json with a node js **or** python lambda function (the language is irrelevant, I just need the results):

```
{
  "stage": "dev",
  "server": {
    "instanceId": "i-xxxx",
    "status": "running"
  },
  "message": [
    {
      "MessageId": "xxx",
      "ReceiptHandle": "xxx",
      "MD5OfBody": "xxx",
      "Body": "{\n  \"stage\": \"DEV\",\n  \"id\": \"5\",\n \"results\": \"D:\\\\Temp\\\\results\"\n}",
      "Attributes": {
        "SenderId": "xxxx",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "xxx",
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "xxx",
        "SequenceNumber": "xxx",
        "MessageDeduplicationId": "20",
        "MessageGroupId": "20"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I just need the "message.Body"-Part. I'd like to split this into three vars for further actions:

```
{
  "stage":"DEV",
  "id":"5",
  "results":"D:\\Temp\\results"
}
```

Could someone help me with this? I just spent the last hour with JSON.stringify , parse, unescape and so on, unfortunately without success :(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! Please refer to our guidelines on [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this community, we try to ask questions after we have done research by ourselves or attempting different solutions. I encourage you to add whatever code you have attempted and ask an specific question about the errors or unexpected behaviours you find. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```py
import json
jsondata = {
  "stage": "dev",
  "server": {
    "instanceId": "i-xxxx",
    "status": "running"
  },
  "message": [
    {
      "MessageId": "xxx",
      "ReceiptHandle": "xxx",
      "MD5OfBody": "xxx",
      "Body": "{\n  \"stage\": \"DEV\",\n  \"id\": \"5\",\n \"results\": \"D:\\\\Temp\\\\results\"\n}",
      "Attributes": {
        "SenderId": "xxxx",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "xxx",
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "xxx",
        "SequenceNumber": "xxx",
        "MessageDeduplicationId": "20",
        "MessageGroupId": "20"
      }
    }
  ]
}
jsonbody = json.loads(jsondata.get('message')[0].get('Body'))
print(jsonbody)
# {'stage': 'DEV', 'id': '5', 'results': 'D:\\Temp\\results'}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! U just saved me lots of try and errors! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way of implementing it in Python,

```
import json

dic = {
  "stage": "dev",
  "server": {
    "instanceId": "i-xxxx",
    "status": "running"
  },
  "message": [
    {
      "MessageId": "xxx",
      "ReceiptHandle": "xxx",
      "MD5OfBody": "xxx",
      "Body": "{\n  \"stage\": \"DEV\",\n  \"id\": \"5\",\n \"results\": \"D:\\\\Temp\\\\results\"\n}",
      "Attributes": {
        "SenderId": "xxxx",
        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "xxx",
        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
        "SentTimestamp": "xxx",
        "SequenceNumber": "xxx",
        "MessageDeduplicationId": "20",
        "MessageGroupId": "20"
      }
    }
  ]
}

message_body_str = dic['message'][0]['Body']
print(json.dumps(json.loads(message_body_str)))
```